# how to uninstall sonarqube-6.4.1 from ubuntu

Tags: sonarqube

h all ,
i am trying to uninstall sonarqube from the ubuntu machine using command "sudo apt-get remove --purge autoremove sonarqube-6.4.1" but I am getting error as no packages foun some one kindly help me with uninstalling soanrqube complaetly from ubuntu machine

Answer (score 2):

Your `purge` isn't working because SonarQube likely wasn't installed via `apt-get`. So how was it installed? The docs offer clues:

[Installing the Web Server](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server#InstallingtheServer-installingWebServerInstallingtheWebServer) tells you to download the SonarQube zip, expand it, and configure the properties file. So your first step would be to wipe out the SonarQube directory.

Of course, if SonarQube is [running as a service](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Linux) on your machine, just deleting the diretory could lead to errors at the next startup, so you'll need to unwind that part too. For *setting up* a service, the docs advise you to:

- create `/etc/init.d/sonar`
- create a link in `/usr/bin/sonar` to the SonarQube start script
- update your defaults

So you'll want to back those things out too.

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni if this answer helped you solve your problem, you might want to accept it.